# Recursive search for own filesystem

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to search a FSElement which can be either file or directory to find in a file structure whose root is localroot directory and then onwards trying to find but it does not return me expected results. Can anyone suggest me where am I wrong.

```
private FSElement getTargetFromName(String targetName) throws CommandNotExecutedException {
            fsElement = localroot.getChildren();
            Iterator<FSElement> children = fsElement.iterator();
            while (children.hasNext()) {

                FSElement child = children.next();
                if (child.isDirectory()) {
                    if (child.getName().equals(targetName))
                        return child;
                    else {
                        localroot = (Directory) child;
                        return getTargetFromName(targetName);
                    }
                } else if (child.getName().equals(targetName))
                    return child;
            }
            throw new CommandNotExecutedException("Destination file/dir not found");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying and thats what is happening. I am wondering as I am writing this line 
localroot = (Directory) child; 

Does it not change the localroot to new localroot for next recursion?

Comment: My previous comment was a dumb mistake. The problem is with throwing the CommandNotExecutedException(""); exception. The moment you reach a leaf file that is not the target file, you will throw the error.

Comment: Thank you, But I am iterating through(while loop) all the Children(including dir/file) after that only i throw the exception. Anyway do you recommend any solution?

Comment: You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that while searching, if you encounter a file that does not match the target file, you throw an error. You won't be able to throw an error through recursive searching without a helper method, instead you could do something like this instead.

This is completely untested, but in theory should work.

```
    private FSElement getTargetFromName (FSElement root, String targetName) {
        Iterator<FSElement> children = root.iterator();
        while (children.hasNext()) {
            FSElement child = children.next();
            if (child.getName().equals(targetName)) {
                return child;
            } else if (child.isDirectory()) {
                FSElement searched = getTargetFromName(child, targetName);
                if (searched != null) {
                    return searched;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If you want to have it throw an error, you could add a helper method such as:

```
public FSElement getTargetFromName (String targetName) throws CommandNotExecutedException {
    FSElement file = getTargetFromName(localroot, targetName);
    if (file == null) {
        throw new CommandNotExecutedException("Destination file/dir not found");
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zachary. I will try this as solution and let me come back. I got it that it returns exception as it hits the bottom nodes.

Comment: In your initial solution you threw an error the moment you searched an entire directory and did not find the file during any recursive call to getTargetFromName. With depth-first recursion, you need to be careful how you handle the leaf nodes.